# container won't let add me responsive image sizing Joomla

Tags: css, image, joomla, responsive, responsive-images

Im trying to add responsive sizing but Joomla won't take it. It won't accept the 50% as % it takes it as px.
I want to add responsive sizing for the images when you size down the website view.

[image]

This is the code I`m using

```html
<div class="image123">
  <div style="float: links; margin-right: 5px;" width="50%" height="auto">
    <img class="mouseoverzoom" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Vergil Stationary" /></div>
  <div style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;">
    <img class="mouseoverzoom" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" width="531" height="340" /></div>
  <div style="float: links; margin-right: 5px;"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" height="200" width="200" /></div>
</div>
```

this also does not work

```
<div style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;"><img class="mouseoverzoom" src="images/ary.jpg" width="50%" height="50%" /></div>
```

Comment: `float: links` needs translation. :)

Comment: Also, div elements don't have `width`  or `height` attributes. See  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div.

Comment: You'd be wise to abandon inline styles and use a [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) element instead. Also, use an editor that knows HTML better than you do. It'll point out problems.

Comment: Finally, floats are a poor layout mechanism. They're fraught with pitfalls and were never intended to align structural elements. Use inline-block display or [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead.

Comment: Since there are so many issues here I'd suggest you make some of those corrections and post a new question with a more specific goal stated. It's not clear what you're trying to do. See [ask].

Comment: We can see the problem. We don't know your desired outcome. As I said, though, you need to fix all those problems first.

Comment: I encourage Joomla users, to join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask their Joomla-related questions there.

Comment: Give us a link to the site you're making the edit. I also think this is a HTML/CSS issue and not Joomla perse.

Answer (score 0):

The standard value scale for inline attributes "width" and "height" for img tag in HTML is in pixels, you need to add a css class to this img element so that you can use percentage scale for sizing.
you may change it like this :

```
<img class="mouseoverzoom" src="images/ary.jpg" class="resized" />
```

and then add the .resized class to css stylesheet like this:

```
img.resized {
width:50%;
height: 50%;
}
```

there is a nice guide in this link

https://imagekit.io/blog/how-to-resize-image-in-html/